# Applying CSS to JavaFX TextAreas

Tags: css, javafx

I want to change the background color of a TextArea using CSS. I'm using this line:

```
-fx-control-inner-background: #00FF99;
```

The problem is that the TextArea only displays this color when it has focus. I know TextAreas are composed of several different Nodes. Do I have to alter another one to make the color remain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I played around with all the CSS tags and here's what worked:

`-fx-base: #00FF99;
 -fx-control-inner-background: #00FF99;`

It seems that `-fx-base` changes the actual background color of the TextArea and `-fx-control-inner-background` changes the color of the TextArea when selected.

Answer (score 0):

`-fx-control-inner-background` is a generic css style created in JavaFX default styling files to  color the inside of `text boxes`, `password boxes`, `lists`, `trees`, etc.

Its better to use the following css, to color just the content of the `TextArea`

```
.text-area .content {
    -fx-background-color: #00FF99;
}
```

Comment: Something interesting happened here. The TextArea is still white but when it gets focus, the entire background takes that blue color that surrounds text boxes when selected.